# Django & DRF: trying to find a way to reuse code for user registration for web and REST api

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a working Django based web experience that has a CustomUser (AbstractUser) model to remove username and require email as default. I implemented a "register" function within views.py that set is_email_verified to FALSE (which is only set to TRUE by the email verification component).

Now, I am creating REST services that could be used by a mobile app. I find the logic for the register function within api/views.py to be very similar to the register function within the views.py supporting the web experience. While I can extract the common code into a common function (and call it from both web and api register functions), is it a bad practice to instead update the web register function as follows (and call it from the POST function within the api/views):

web views.py:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes([AllowAny])
@csrf_exempt
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.content_type == 'application/json':
            # registration via API call 
            data = json.loads(request.body)
            user_form = UserRegistrationForm(data)
        else:
            # registration via web
            user_form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)

        if user_form.is_valid():
            new_user = user_form.save(commit=False)
            new_user.set_password(user_form.cleaned_data['password'])
            new_user.is_email_verified = False
            new_user.save()
            Profile.objects.create(user=new_user)
            send_email_verification_email(request, new_user)

            if request.content_type == 'application/json':
                # API response with token
                token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=new_user)
                if created:
                    return Response({'message': _('User registered successfully'), \
                    'token': token.key, 'created': True})
                else:
                    return Response({'message': _('User registration failed'), \
                    'token': token.key, 'created': False})
            else:
                # Web response
                return render(request, 'useracct/register_done.html', {'new_user': new_user})
    else:
        user_form = UserRegistrationForm()

   return render(request, 'useracct/register.html', {'user_form': user_form})
```

In api/views.py:

```
class UserRegisterAPIView(APIView): 
    def post(self, request): 
        register(request)
        return request
```

Looking for best practice from experienced Django developers. Cheers.